# @Html.TextBox not showing Value on Post

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am having some issues with my form. I am not getting the values on the textboxes on Post. It faults out because `lstdata` is null..

Here is my controller Post:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Add(Guid vid, IEnumerable<PartsViewModel> lstdata)
    {
        try
        {
            var userid = User.Identity.GetUserId();
            var user = User.Identity.Name;
            var str = "BE";
            var date = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddmmss");
            string RFQNum = str + date;
            RFQViewModel rfqmodel = new RFQViewModel
            {
                VendorId = vid,
                CreatedBy = user,
                RFQNumber = RFQNum,
                EmailStatus = false,
                RequestDate = System.DateTime.Now,
                TotalQuantity = lstdata.Sum(a => a.QtySelected)
            };
            var entity = rfqmodel.RFQToEntity();
            var IsEmailSent = db.RFQs.Where(a => a.VendorId == rfqmodel.VendorId).FirstOrDefault();
            if (IsEmailSent != null)
            {
                IsEmailSent.EmailStatus = true;
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
            db.RFQs.Add(entity);
            db.SaveChanges();
            foreach (var item in lstdata)
            {
                if (item.QtySelected > 0)
                {
                    RFQDetailsViewModel rFQDetailsViewModel = new RFQDetailsViewModel
                    {
                        CreatedBy = userid,
                        Material = item.Material,
                        VendorRef = item.VendorRef,
                        Quantity = item.QtySelected,
                        RFQId = entity.RFQId
                    };
                    var rfqdetailentity = rFQDetailsViewModel.RFQDetailsToEntity();
                    db.RFQDetails.Add(rfqdetailentity);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                }
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "RFQ");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

Here is the view:

```
  @using (Html.BeginForm("Add", "RFQ", FormMethod.Post))
            {
                @Html.Hidden("vid", Model.Vendor.VendorId)
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="box box-primary">
                            <div class="box-header">
                                <h3 class="box-title">Parts</h3>
                            </div><!-- /.box-header -->
                            <div class="box-body table-responsive">
                                <table class="table table-hover table-bordered" id="partsTable">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>
                                                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Parts.PartImage)
                                            </th>
                                            <th>
                                                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Parts.PartNumber)
                                            </th>
                                            <th>
                                                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Parts.VendorRef)
                                            </th>
                                            <th>
                                                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.TotalQuantity)
                                                &nbsp; -
                                                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => Model.Parts.UnitOfMeasure)
                                            </th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                        @{
                                            for (int i = 0; i < Model.Partitem.Count; i++)
                                            {
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td>
                                                        @if (Model.Partitem[i].PartImage != null)
                                                        {
                                                            <img class="group list-group-image center" style="width:50px;" src="~/UploadedDocuments/PartsImages/@Model.Partitem[i].PartImage" alt="" />
                                                        }
                                                        else
                                                        {
                                                            <img class="group list-group-image center" style="width:50px;" src="~/Content/Images/Parts/NoImage.png" alt="" />
                                                        }
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <label>@Model.Partitem[i].PartNumber</label>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <label>@Model.Partitem[i].VendorReference</label>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12">
                                                            @Html.Hidden("[" + i + "].Material", Model.Partitem[i].Material)
                                                            @Html.TextBox("[" + i + "].QtySelected") &nbsp;
                                                            @Model.Partitem[i].UnitOfMeasure
                                                        </div>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                            }
                                        }
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            <input type="submit" value="AddRFQ" class="  btn btn-default btn-sm" id="add" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            }
```

And here is the Model:

```
    public class PartsViewModel
{
    public Guid Material { get; set; }
    public string VendorRef { get; set; }
    public Guid VendorId { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public decimal SellingPrice { get; set; }
    public decimal MachinedPrice { get; set; }
    public int? UnitsInStock { get; set; }
    public string PartImage { get; set; }
    public string LeadTime { get; set; }
    public int QtySelected { get; set; }
    public string DrawingNumber { get; set; }
    public string ExtDescription { get; set; }
    public decimal StandardCost { get; set; }
    public decimal AverageCost { get; set; }

    public decimal LastCost { get; set; }
    public string PrimaryVendor { get; set; }
    public string UnitOfMeasure { get; set; }
    public string VendorReference { get; set; }
    //public string VendorRef { get; set; }
    public string ImagePath { get; set; }
    public string PartNumber { get; set; }
    public bool? InStockQuanex { get; set; }
    public bool Status { get; set; }
    public HttpPostedFileBase PartImageUpload { get; set; }
    //public List<Vendors> Vendors { get; set; }
    //public List<Parts> Parts { get; set; }
    public List<ExtParts> Parts { get; set; }
    //public ProductMaster ProdMaster { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> VendorList { get; set; }
}
```

This is the Model for the page:

```
    public class RFQViewModel 
{
    [Key]
    public Guid RFQId { get; set; }
    public Guid VendorId { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = " Email Status")]
    public bool? EmailStatus { get; set; }

    public bool? OrderStatus { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = " Request Date")]
    public DateTime? RequestDate { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Total Quantity")]
    public int TotalQuantity { get; set; }
    public DateTime? CreatedDate { get; set; }

    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }

    public DateTime? UpdatedDate { get; set; }
    public string Vname { get; set; }
    public string UpdatedBy { get; set; }
    public Guid Materials { get; set; }
    public string RFQNumber { get; set; }
    public string Quantity { get; set; }

    public bool? IsDelete { get; set; }

    public Vendors Vendor { get; set; }

    public Guid[] SelectedParts { get; set; }
    public List<PartsViewModel> Partitem { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> Part { get; set; }
    //public Parts Parts { get; set; }
    public ExtParts Parts { get; set; }
    public List<RFQDetailsViewModel> Rfqdetails { get; set; }
    //public ProductMaster ProdMaster { get; set; }
   
}
```

Sorry for all the code. I try to keep it short, but for this I needed to show all of it.
I am assuming it is something in the View but I am troubleshooting something someone else did.

Thanks for your help..

UPDATE:

I decided to add the `HttpGet` code so that it is complete.

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Add (Guid id)
    {
        try
        {
            var userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
            RFQViewModel r = new RFQViewModel();
            GeneralEntities cn = new GeneralEntities();
            List<PartsViewModel> Apart = new List<PartsViewModel>();
            r.SelectedParts = db.ProductMaster.Where(a => a.VendorId == id).Select(a => a.Material).ToArray();
            //Apart = db.PartsView.Where(k => r.SelectedParts.Contains(k.Material)).Select(v => new PartsViewModel
            Apart = db.ExtParts.Where(k => r.SelectedParts.Contains(k.Material)).Select(v => new PartsViewModel
            {
                Material = v.Material,
                PartNumber = v.PartNumber,
                VendorReference = v.VendorRef,
                PartImage = v.PartImage,
                UnitOfMeasure = v.UnitOfMeasure
            }).ToList();
            r.Partitem = Apart;
            r.RFQId = Guid.NewGuid();
            r.Vendor = db.Vendors.Where(d => d.VendorId == id).FirstOrDefault();
            var Check = db.RFQs.Where(k => k.VendorId == id).OrderByDescending(K => K.CreatedDate).FirstOrDefault();
            if (Check != null)
            {
                var diff = (System.DateTime.Now - Check.RequestDate).Value;
                var days = diff.Days;
                if (days < 7)
                {
                    ViewBag.msg = "You Have created order for This Vendor  before... <a href='/RFQ/Details/ " + Check.RFQId + "'>Click here</a>";
                }
            }
            return View(r);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

Also the View is `@model MyProject.Models.RFQViewModel`

UPDATE:

I have found my issue. Strangely the fact that I have this in a dataTable, using `dataTable` that is what is causing the issue.. I commented the Javascript for the dataTabe out and it works.

So If anyone knows how to correct this so it does work using a `dataTable` It would be much appreciated. Some of the lists are long and using a `dataTable` makes it much easier to navigate. If not I will have to live with it..

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the model went to view with null values, so you had to define these lines. The model had to be initialized. Of course, I did a test.

```
var model = new RFQViewModel();
model.Partitem = new List<PartsViewModel>()
{
    new PartsViewModel(){PartImage ="",Material=new Guid("7C04E93E-9CB6-4F2C-822F-68D1A9E59581")},
    new PartsViewModel(){PartImage ="",Material=new Guid("59AFE3A1-5659-4191-B399-1F6F3FC84614")},
    new PartsViewModel(){PartImage ="",Material=new Guid("60B3EF82-3661-48D6-BD2E-25FB4268A11F")}
};
model.Vendor = new Vendors();
model.Vendor.VendorId = 15;

return View(model);
```

I made the necessary changes. Change your code as follows

**change action to**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Add(RFQViewModel model)
{
    //...............
    return View(model);
}
```

**change view to**

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Vendor.VendorId)

//
//************
//
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12">
     @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Partitem[i].Material)
     @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Partitem[i].QtySelected) &nbsp;
     @Model.Partitem[i].UnitOfMeasure
</div>
```

Comment: This does not work. Also the form may have more than 1 and the IEnumerable<PartsViewModel> lstdata is there for the collection and to get what is needed. Also lstdata is used to get a total quantity of selected parts.

Comment: Take a look above. I added what is causing the issue.

Comment: I simulated your classes and did not know the data type of some members and gave the data type of myself. And the complete list was sent with new data

Comment: As I stated above. My code works. It is because i have it in a dataTable that it did not. If you know how to have it work using a datatable that would be helpful, if not I can live with the long lists..